# Looking for way to sell 3D models without sharing my personal info

Tags: 3d, business, modeling

I've been practicing 3D modelling for a few months now. I want to find a way to sell models, maybe make models on commission. However, at least at the beginning I don't want to do this using my real name / let people see my personal info. Are there any sites or ways where I can do this? I mean where the site can see my personal info but doesn't share it with people who buy the models, so handles selling / payment indirectly.

Comment: *Every* stock image reseller operates how you've described. The site knows who you are, but users purchasing only see your chosen username.

Comment: @Scott You mean they are basically buying from the site, and then the site pays me whatever-percent of that, so users don't see my name and paypal info and such?

Comment: Exactly what he means.

Comment: Exactly. The only ones that actually know who you are are the site owners/operators themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websites like [Fiverr.com](https://www.fiverr.com/) allow you to do freelance work relatively anonymously. As a matter of fact, it's against [Fiverr's policy](https://www.fiverr.com/terms_of_service) to share your personal information on the platform. Working this way would be more like if someone asks for something specific and you create it custom for them, as opposed to having a stock built up and just sell them passively like on shutterstock.

There is, of course, the option to create your own website that allows users to purchase downloads. I used [BigCommerce.com](https://www.bigcommerce.com/) last year to open a store and BigCommerce handles all of the payments for you where the seller and the buyer never directly share information. While your profits will be much higher on a platform like that, all of the advertisement will be up to you, since you are pretty much running your own business. On Fiverr, you are part of a community and that can help you get noticed much more easily.

Comment: Thanks! I'm also checking out CGTrader, they do have a "Freelance Projects" option but don't yet know how that works.

Comment: Great! I haven't heard of that one but I bet a niche website like that would work even better than a generic freelance site.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly every stock website will let you sell assets under an username of your choice, which can be anything, then your personal data is only used privately for payments and all that.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any sites who let you do commissions / freelance this anon way?

Comment: Shutterstock probably the largest, Graphic River, and many others.

Comment: Thanks! What I mean by commission is someone requests a specific model / image from you and you make the model and the site handles the payment for you. So you are not directly making business with that person.

Comment: Then you need to look for on-demand job websites like Upwork, Fiverr, Freelancer.com and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at sites like [**TurboSquid**](https://www.turbosquid.com/), [**CGTrader**](https://www.cgtrader.com/), [**3DOcean**](https://3docean.net/), [**Evermotion**](https://evermotion.org/), [**CreativeMarket**](https://creativemarket.com/3d) or even Adobe's 3D assets store for its proprietary 3D tools... all of them use a similar modality to those stock sites already mentioned - though most of the previous ones mentioned were image based versus model based (which these all are).

If you have enough skill and proficiency, you might also be able to sell assets for specific game engines in each of those asset stores, as many independent games developers are not hotshot modelers themselves - I know the [**Unity Asset Store**](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/) has a slew of 3d assets from free through quite expensive, and from barely passable quality through to better than I could produce myself; I would imagine the same to be true for Unreal as well.

OH - hey yeah - if you *ARE* really good ***and*** you excel at high clarity, good edge flow poly and Sub-D modeling *and* can do *excellent* quality architectural and environment assets, you could see about submitting models to [**Kitbash 3D**](https://kitbash3d.com/) - they do top-flight work, work with only excellent modelers, and they do specifically commission thematic work from those modelers - they charge real money for excellent quality assets, and the artist get paid pretty well.

Comment: Thanks! As for Kitbash, I'm not that good yet:). I'm not bad with low-poly models though.